# Valid sim card occasionally not being detected

Tags: sim-card

My android (TLC 767w) Will occasionally lose all network access, reporting an error that sim card could not be detected and giving an annoying ping every minute or so at me.  I've always been able to get the phone to detect the sim card eventually, but I'm worried it may be a problem that will grow worse or strand me at an inconvenient time without access.   So far the issues have only happened when roaming out of my home state.  I couldn't imagine why my physical location would matter for detecting the sim card and so presumed the fact that it always happened out of state was a fluke, but the last two times in particular seemed suspiciously (in)convenient timing if location didn't matter so not sure what to think now.

I've tried looking up causes for sim card errors and none of them seemed to help.  I checking and cleaning the physical sim card, not really sure how much that would help.  I've tried changing network status, resetting network and connecting to one manually etc without help.  I hadn't made any noticeable changes to third party apps around the time the error appeared so I don't think that is the cause of the problem.

A bit more detail on each time this happened.

- First time was many states away.  Issue persisted for days and after I returned home, which was when I realized it was a sim card issue and not just being out of network.  A reboot immediately fixed it but only after it stayed broken after I went home.
  (I tweaked some network settings trying to figure out cause of networking issue this first time, not sure if that matters)
- Second time reboot fixed the problem while still many states away.
- Third time an 1.5 hr north of my home.  The 'reboot' option didn't fix it, but shutting down phone, waiting a few minutes for all capacitors to drain, and then rebooting did.
- Fourth and fifth times a month later on same trip as third time.  Lost network connection at roughly the same point in the drive.  Repeated reboots of any type didn't fix it, but the network did seem to come back on its own eventually as I drove back towards my home state without a reboot.  This seemed really odd, it stayed broken for hours away from my home and fixed itself only as I approached home...
- It may or may not have happened one other time very close to my home.  I lost network connection where I know I should have had it, but never got the error message about being unable to detect the sim card.  I probably should have waited longer to see if the error showed up (it always seems to take a bit for the error to be reported, I waited as long as it usually took for the error to appear at least) but I was in a hurry so rebooted the phone and network connection came back.

So yeah not sure what to do next.  I'm trying to figure out the likely causes, if I can do anything to minimize the problem and/or if I should expect it to grow worse over time, and rather a replacement of my android is likely to help or be necessary.

Comment: How old is the used SIM card? Ich you look at the contact pads of the sim card are there deep scratches visible that could prevent electrical contact?